# XSL Contains that returns true if anything matches

Tags: xml, xslt

Hey I want the below to return true if any of it matches (For Example, it should return true because it contains randomstuff even though the first part doesn't match).

```
contains('otherrandomstuff', 'blargrandomstuff')
```

Cheers

Comment: Have you thought this through? What **exactly** would constitute a "match"? Seems even a single common character would suffice in your method.  -- P.S. Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: The best way is to CONCAT both strings and check if any pair repeats in that string.

Comment: @usermesamjosein And how exactly would *that* work?

Comment: -In the 'otherrandomstuffblargrandomstuff' string use a loop to take character count.

-Skip characters with < 2 count.

-Combine the remaining words and check if the character combination repeats.

Comment: @usermesamjosein What "remaining words"? IIUC, your test will return positive for "aa" & "bb". If not, why don't you post this as an answer with actual **code** we can follow?

Comment: Sure Mr.Michael, Once I get some time for this. I'm glad if someone would work on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible (not very efficient) algorithm:

(1) Find all characters that appear in both strings. Call this the common subset.

(2) In both strings, find all substrings consisting only of characters in the common subset

(3) Find the substrings that are in both sets

(4) Of these, take the longest

(5) Report success if this is longer than some threshold.

However, I'm not going to go any further in terms of producing working code because I strongly suspect you haven't thought the requirement through fully. Before writing code, I would want to know what you are trying to achieve. Also, while attempting this in XSLT 2.0 is quite feasible, an XSLT 1.0 solution would be pretty grotesque.

Comment: If there's a threshold, then it's not necessary to look for the longest match. You could find the (Boolean) answer in `b - n + 1` iterations of `contains()` - where `b` is the string-length of the shorter string and `n` is the threshold. Perfectly feasible in XSLT 1.0.